# ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

I get an error "ORA-00947: not enough values") inserting a record and can't see why! It seems to me I have the correct number of parameters:

```
string sQuery = "insert into EventLog (UserEventLogID, USERID, EVENTSEVERITYID, LOGTIME_TZ, USEREVENTTYPEID, USEREVENTMSG) " +
    "values (0, :USERID, :EVENTSEVERITYID, cast(:LOGTIME_TZ as Timestamp(6) With Time Zone) at time zone '" + oLog.TimeZone + "'), " +
    ":EVENTTYPEID, :EVENTMSG) " +
    " returning USEREVENTLOGID into :EventLogID";

    oraCmd = new OracleCommand();
    oraCmd.BindByName = true;
    oraCmd.Parameters.Add("EVENTSEVERITYID", OracleDbType.Int16, 2, oLog.EventSeverityID, ParameterDirection.Input);
    oraCmd.Parameters.Add("LOGTIME_TZ", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, 6, oLog.EventTimestamp, ParameterDirection.Input);
    oraCmd.Parameters.Add("EVENTTYPEID", OracleDbType.Int16, 4, oLog.EventTypeID, ParameterDirection.Input);
    oraCmd.Parameters.Add("EVENTMSG", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 300, oLog.EventMsg, ParameterDirection.Input);
    oraCmd.Parameters.Add("USERID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, oLog.UserID, ParameterDirection.Input);

    outParam = new OracleParameter("EventLogID", OracleDbType.Decimal);
    outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oraCmd.Parameters.Add(outParam);
```

the table has one more column "LGTIME" which is nullable so I did not include it in insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an extra ")" .
    cast(:LOGTIME_TZ as Timestamp(6) With Time Zone) **<-----** at time zone '" + oLog.TimeZone + "')