# SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Learning Oracle SQL. I have created a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Kocury
    (imie VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    plec VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT allowedValues CHECK (plec in ('M', 'D')),
    pseudo VARCHAR2(15) Constraint PK_KOCURY PRIMARY KEY,
    funkcja VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT   fk_checkF REFERENCES Funkcje (funkcja), 
    szef VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT fk_checkS references Kocury (pseudo),
    w_stadku_od DATE default sysdate, 
    przydzial_myszy NUMBER(3),
    myszy_extra NUMBER(3),
    nr_bandy NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT fk_checkN REFERENCES Bandy(nr_bandy)
);`
```

and then I tried to insert some data:

`INSERT INTO Kocury(imie, plec, pseudo, funkcja, szef, w_stadku_od, przydzial_myszy ,myszy_extra, nr_bandy)
VALUES ('JACEK', 'M', 'PLACEK', 'LOWCZY', 'LYSY', '2008-12-01, 67',NULL , 2);`

as far as I am concerned the data types all match. But in Oracle SQL Developer I get this:

`Error starting at line : 41 in command -
INSERT INTO Kocury(imie, plec, pseudo, funkcja, szef, w_stadku_od, przydzial_myszy ,myszy_extra, nr_bandy) 
VALUES ('JACEK', 'M', 'PLACEK', 'LOWCZY', 'LYSY', '2008-12-01, 67',NULL , 2)
Error at Command Line : 42 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:

*Action:`

I am not sure what's happening and how to get my data inserted. What could I be doing wrong? These topics didn't help me: 
[ORA-00947 : Not Enough Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649379/ora-00947-not-enough-values)
[ORA-00947: not enough values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098907/ora-00947-not-enough-values)

Comment: `'2008-12-01, 67'` is not a valid date.  Also, this has nothing to do with MySQL or SQL Server

Comment: If you're learning, don't start with the bad habit of inserting dates using string values that rely on your NLS settings. In addition to sgeddes's correction, use `to_date('2008-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` or a date literal since you're using the ISO format anyway, `DATE '2008-12-01'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing some apostrophes in between `'2008-12-01, 67'`:

```
INSERT INTO Kocury(imie, plec, pseudo, funkcja, szef, w_stadku_od, przydzial_myszy ,myszy_extra, nr_bandy) 
VALUES ('JACEK', 'M', 'PLACEK', 'LOWCZY', 'LYSY', '2008-12-01', 67, NULL , 2)
```